# Extended Nested if statements in Excel: error in processing

Tags: excel, if-statement, filter, nested

I want to use nested if statements as a method of filtering data in Excel, and have written a series of nested if statements, however, the code won't compile in the Excel formula line and comes up with an error saying "the formula you typed contains an error", but I don't know where the error could be.

IF(FILTERS!$V$7= "", IF (FILTERS!$AC$7 = "", IF (SHEET1!$T2 = FILTERS!$B$17, IF (SHEET1!$U2 = FILTERS!$C$17, IF (SHEET1!$V2 = FILTERS!$D$17, IF (SHEET1!$W2 = FILTERS!$E$17,  IF (SHEET1!$X2= FILTERS!$F$17, A2, "")  ,""), "" ) ,""),  ""),IF (SHEET1!$M2 = FILTERS!$AC$7, IF (SHEET1!$T2 = FILTERS!$B$17, IF (SHEET1!$U2 = FILTERS!$C$17, IF (SHEET1!$V2 = FILTERS!$D$17, IF (SHEET1!$W2 = FILTERS!$E$17, IF (SHEET1!$X2 = FILTERS!$F$17, A2, ""), ""), "")  ,  "")  , ""), “”)), IF(SHEET1!$H2 = FILTERS!$V$7, IF (FILTERS!$AC$7 = "", IF (SHEET1!$T2 = FILTERS!$B$17, IF (SHEET1!$U2 = FILTERS!$C$17, IF (SHEET1!$V2 = FILTERS!$D$17, IF (SHEET1!$W2 = FILTERS!$E$17,  IF (SHEET1!$X2= FILTERS!$F$17, A2, "")  ,""), "" ) ,""),  ""), ""),IF (SHEET1!$M2 = FILTERS!$AC$7, IF (SHEET1!$T2 = FILTERS!$B$17, IF (SHEET1!$U2 = FILTERS!$C$17, IF (SHEET1!$V2 = FILTERS!$D$17, IF (SHEET1!$W2 = FILTERS!$E$17, IF (SHEET1!$X2 = FILTERS!$F$17, A2, ""), ""), "")  , "")  , ""), ""), ""))

Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It gets very difficult as the complexity rises. You can try a web site such as [Excel Formula Beautifier](http://excelformulabeautifier.com/) which will attempt to format your formula with indentation. The indentation on your one above looks like this:

```
=IF(
    FILTERS!$V$7 = "",
    IF ( FILTERS!$AC$7 = "" , IF ( SHEET1!$T2 = FILTERS!$B$17 , IF ( SHEET1!$U2 = FILTERS!$C$17 , IF ( SHEET1!$V2 = FILTERS!$D$17 , IF ( SHEET1!$W2 = FILTERS!$E$17 , IF ( SHEET1!$X2 = FILTERS!$F$17 , A2 , "" ) , "" ) , "" ) , "" ) , "" ) , IF ( SHEET1!$M2 = FILTERS!$AC$7 , IF ( SHEET1!$T2 = FILTERS!$B$17 , IF ( SHEET1!$U2 = FILTERS!$C$17 , IF ( SHEET1!$V2 = FILTERS!$D$17 , IF ( SHEET1!$W2 = FILTERS!$E$17 , IF ( SHEET1!$X2 = FILTERS!$F$17 , A2 , "" ) , "" ) , "" ) , "" ) , "" ) , “” ) ),
    IF(
        SHEET1!$H2 = FILTERS!$V$7,
        IF ( FILTERS!$AC$7 = "" , IF ( SHEET1!$T2 = FILTERS!$B$17 , IF ( SHEET1!$U2 = FILTERS!$C$17 , IF ( SHEET1!$V2 = FILTERS!$D$17 , IF ( SHEET1!$W2 = FILTERS!$E$17 , IF ( SHEET1!$X2 = FILTERS!$F$17 , A2 , "" ) , "" ) , "" ) , "" ) , "" ) , "" ),
        IF ( SHEET1!$M2 = FILTERS!$AC$7 , IF ( SHEET1!$T2 = FILTERS!$B$17 , IF ( SHEET1!$U2 = FILTERS!$C$17 , IF ( SHEET1!$V2 = FILTERS!$D$17 , IF ( SHEET1!$W2 = FILTERS!$E$17 , IF ( SHEET1!$X2 = FILTERS!$F$17 , A2 , "" ) , "" ) , "" ) , "" ) , "" ) , "" ),
        ""
    )
)
```

which would imply at least a problem where there are more than 3 arguments to the if (the inner one is showing four). If you can, build it up one if at a time, or use multiple columns to simplify each individual expression.